# What could be the optimal way to find out nearest item to given coordinate

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two tables Prisma[MySql tables] a and b where a is collections of items and b is location table for each item in the table a.

NOTE: Both table size is going to be HUGE

table.a

```
{
  _id: 'any random item id'
  itemName: 'Bla Bla',
  itemLocation: table.b
}
```

table.b

```
{
  _id: 'unique id',
  latitude: 51.006,
  longitutde: 7.00
}
```

Now I have to find out which item in the table.a is closest to given geo coordinates. geo coordinates are passed in POST params of the express server. Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: Hi, not direct answer to your question - when we had similar challenge (it was even more difficult - we had to find all the points in certain polygon), we created new microservice just for this purpose, saved all geo locations to it and we used MongoDB. The best thing is - MongoDB has native support for geolocations and you can do this (and much more) with single query and in logharithimic time.
If microservice is not possible, you can still run MongoDB as "sideDB" to these purposes.

Comment: Hmmmm...Will going to think in this direction too :)